# Regex Notepad++ find & replace 2nd set of characters

Tags: regex, notepad++

i have a line of text like

```
CK \t Segamat \t Johor \t 999
```

assume the `\t` is a tab, how can i replace the 2nd `\t` with a space?

so far i can find the line with 3 `\t` = `^(.*?\t.*?)(.*?\t.*?)\t`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find & capture what is between tabs in the find field:

```
^(.*?)\t(.*?)\t(.*?)\t(.*?)$
```

Then replace the tabs between the captured groups in the replace-with field using a space where you want it substituted:

```
\1\t\2 \3\t\4
```