# Regex (Notepad++) - Locate and replace second occurance of a character per line

Tags: regex, notepad++

I would like to change the second forward slash, within each line, to a comma.

I have found various posts and managed to derive a way of doing it from them but it's not doing it how I want.

[Initial attempt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27879492/trying-to-get-string-between-2-delimiters) - I thought I needed to replace between 2 delimiters

[1st "Replace 2nd occurrence"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24141525/regex-to-replace-second-occurrence-of-a-character) - Found this post which seemed easier.

[2nd "Replace 2nd occurrence"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8910893/regex-notepad-find-replace-2nd-set-of-characters)- Used the regex in here as a base for mine.

What I am doing is;

Find:

`^(.*?)\/(.*?)\/`

Replace:

`$&,`

Which results in changing my data from;

`042146/OVERNIGHT/HSSC825571,started,14/07/2016,00:00:56,V0700LWHSB`
`042146/OVERNIGHT/HSSC825571,ended,14/07/2016,00:00:56,`
`042147/OVERNIGHT/HSSC825571,started,14/07/2016,00:00:58,V0700LWHSB`
`042147/OVERNIGHT/HSSC825571,ended,14/07/2016,00:00:58,`

To;

`042146/OVERNIGHT/,HSSC825571,started,14/07/2016,00:00:56,V0700LWHSB`
`042146/OVERNIGHT/,HSSC825571,ended,14/07/2016,00:00:56,`
`042147/OVERNIGHT/,HSSC825571,started,14/07/2016,00:00:58,V0700LWHSB`
`042147/OVERNIGHT/,HSSC825571,ended,14/07/2016,00:00:58,`

Is there a way of just replacing the second /?

An example set of my data is;

`042146/OVERNIGHT/HSSC825571,started,14/07/2016,00:00:56,V0700LWHSB`
`042146/OVERNIGHT/HSSC825571,ended,14/07/2016,00:00:56,`
`042147/OVERNIGHT/HSSC825571,started,14/07/2016,00:00:58,V0700LWHSB`
`042147/OVERNIGHT/HSSC825571,ended,14/07/2016,00:00:58,`
`042154/TEMP56/QPADEV000M,started,14/07/2016,00:01:02,V0700LRFIN`
`042154/TEMP56/QPADEV000M,ended,14/07/2016,00:07:12,`
`042155/JMALICKA/QPADEV000N,started,14/07/2016,00:01:05,V0700LRFIN`
`042155/JMALICKA/QPADEV000N,ended,14/07/2016,00:06:53,`
`042156/DG8SVCPRF/DG8SVC,started,14/07/2016,00:01:15,DATAGATE`
`042156/DG8SVCPRF/DG8SVC,ended,14/07/2016,00:12:01,`
`042157/OVERNIGHT/RCPTDISCRP,started,14/07/2016,00:01:42,V0700LBATC`
`042157/OVERNIGHT/RCPTDISCRP,ended,14/07/2016,00:01:44,`
`042158/QTCP/QTSMTPCLTP,started,14/07/2016,00:01:53,QSYSWRK`
`042158/QTCP/QTSMTPCLTP,ended,14/07/2016,01:29:08,`
`042159/QTCP/QTSMTPCLTP,started,14/07/2016,00:01:53,QSYSWRK`
`042159/QTCP/QTSMTPCLTP,ended,14/07/2016,00:19:05,`

Comment: Try `$1/$2,` as your replace string

Comment: @DominicComtois that works, thank you - please could you post it as an answer with a description of what it's doing and I'll mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were almost there. You only need to change your replace string with the following:

`$1/$2,`

### How it works

Your regex was: `^(.*?)\/(.*?)\/`
In Notepad++'s replace string, the dollar sign is used to refer to groups enclosed by parentheses in the regex.

- `$1` refers to the first group, `(.*?)` which is at the beginning of the line, as specified with the `^` character.
- `$2` refers to the second group, also `(.*?)`, but which follows the first `/`.

Since you don't want to replace the first slash, you need `$1/$2` at the beginning of your replace string. But since what follows the second group is another `/` (the 2nd one on the line), you need to replace it with the `,`. That's why the replace string has to be `$1/$2,`. Notice that all characters that are not enclosed by `()`'s need to be re-written in the replace string. Otherwise, they're just omitted (try replace string `$1$2` and you'll see what I mean).

In other editors or programming languages, instead of the `$` sign, the `\` is sometimes used (sometimes doubled) to refer to parenthetic groups. So you could have for instance `\\1/\\2,` or `\1/\2,` as a replace string instead of `$1/$2,`.

Comment: You're welcome! Note that as @Toto pointed out, your regex _could_ be modified to use only one grouping and adjusting the replace string accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^([^/]+/[^/]+)/`
- Replace with: `$1,`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

This will replace the second slash of each line by a comma.